# Static Routes not working (linux)

Tags: linux, routing, route, dd-wrt

I hope everyone is well along with their loved ones.

I Have two  Linux-based Dd-wrt routers, on the main router (router A [10.1.1.1] n66u, small metered-like connection) i have a static route for googlevideo.com servers to go out on router B which has a gigabit connection

For Example I have rr5---sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com (74.125.159.138) route to go out on 10.1.1.2 (router B), the traceroute route works fine from SSH router A or client PC

however pinging it goes out directly ignoring the static routes also clients behind router A have the same result, pinging goes out directly ignoring static routes.

router A

```
route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
74.125.159.138      10.1.1.2     255.255.255.255     UGH    0      0        0 br0

ping rr5---sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com #this is ignoring the static route as ping is higher)
PING rr5---sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com (74.125.159.138): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.159.138: seq=0 ttl=59 time=65.400 ms 

traceroute to rr5---sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com (74.125.159.138), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.1.1.2 (10.1.1.2)  0.753 ms  0.447 ms  0.405 ms
 ...#goes out fine
```

When I watch a the youtube video on the Windows PC using rr5---sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com it ignores the static route in router A, but when i traceroute it, it follows the static route from router A, and when I ping rr5---sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com from the Windows client PC it does not use the static route

From Windows PC behind router A

```
Pinging rr5.sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com [74.125.159.138] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.159.138: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=124
```

if it was going out of router B time=would be about 40ms)

From Windows client behind router A

```
Tracing route to rr5.sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com [74.125.159.138]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  routerA [10.1.1.1]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.1.1.2 #router B takes cover
  3    18 ms    17 ms    17 ms  etc
```

if i create static route on Windows directly bypassing DD-WRT router A entry routes everything works fine.

```
route add 74.125.159.138 mask 255.255.255.255 10.1.1.2

Tracing route to rr5.sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com [74.125.159.138]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.1.1.2
  2    <1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  #and so on

Pinging rr5.sn-vgqsknz7.googlevideo.com [74.125.159.138] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.159.138: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=60  #ping is lower
 OK!
```

any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you also have a static route for IPv6? My guess is that the browser (youtube) might prefer IPv6 over IPv4 (not that I know whether windows ping and/or tracert do v4 by default or not).

Comment: i dont have a static route for ipv6 and i disabled ipv6 on windows as well .